# Mui Datagrid new row on top

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

Using mui/x-data-grid I have a grid with a button to ad a new row. It works fin except that the new added row appears at the end of the grid, which is inconvenient if there are a lot of rows. How to make it appear on top?

Here is the code for the new row

```
    {
        // Create a new row object with a unique ID and default property values
        const newRow = { id: uuidv4(), reg_name: "", reg_created: '' };
        setRegions([...regions, newRow]);
    };
```

I also tried to revers it (setRegions([newRow, ...regions])) but it doen't help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `unshift`, and use the function version of `useState`.

```js
const [regions, setRegions] = useState([]);

// ...

setRegions((existingRegions) => {
  const updatedRegions = structuredClone(existingRegions);
  const newRow = { id: uuidv4(), reg_name: "", reg_created: '' };
  updatedRegions.unshift(newRow);
  return updatedRegions;
});
```

Also, it looks like the column is sorted by `Name` (descending). So you may need to add some custom sorting logic to the grid for new data or something.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the column sorting. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

or
`setRegions([newRow,...regions]);`